# Hide Panel Page Title from anonymous users

Tags: panels, 7

I need some custom code to hide a panel page title from anonymous users. I want authenticated users to see the title of the page, but not anonymous users. By page, i mean the entire panel page containing different panes. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try anything? What are the issues you are running into?

Comment: I created tabs on the frontpage accessible to only autheticated users, and page title is displayed based on the tabs, but the same frontpage is used by anonymous users also. The page title shows up for authenticated users but makes no sense for anonymous users so i want to hide it